# how to make multiple sys.argv before another sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i have script like this..

```
import mymodule
import argparse
import sys, os

try:
    _, interface, parameter = sys.argv
except ValueError:
    exit(1)


targets = getattr(mymodule, interface.replace('-','_'), None)

if targets is None:
    print('Invalid Argument')


if not isinstance(targets, list):
    targets = [targets]


for target in targets:
    print('\n\n' + target['ip'].upper())
    joanna.mymodule(target, parameter)
```

i executed this script using this..

```
script.py dsw-a1 'show this'
```

`dsw-a1` is `sys.argv[1]`

`'show this'` is `sys.argv[2]`

how to make my script can execute multiple sys.argv[1]

for example :

```
script.py dsw-a1,dsw-a2,asw-b3 'show this'
```

Thank You

Comment: How would you know the difference between `asw-b3` and `'show this'`? Is it that you always have exactly one `'show this'`? is it that `dsw-a1`, `dsw-a2` and `asw-b3` always have a dash, and `'show this'` never does? Python isn't human, you have to explain every little detail. For Python it's not enough to say "well it's obvious they're different'". You might want to use a switch for `'show this'` and not for the rest of them and differentiate them that way. You might want to pack the first ones all up with, as Akshay suggested, a comma. Many different possibilities, and it's on you to pick.

Comment: Don't reinvent the proverbial squared wheel, use the stdlib's solution: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: hi, its ok to use comma, i already edit my post..
and how to make this?

Comment: Please try sys.argv[1].split(",")

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.